# COMP167 Folder: nothing added to commit but untracked files present - change of commit behaviour after GitHub 2-factor authentication

Tags: git, github, git-push

I'm relatively new to github and they have recently required 2-factor authentication. I managed to get that sorted, but now for some reason when I put files in my COMP167 folder and try to commit, it only updates changes to (tracked) files that are already in the folder, and doesn't add the new files.

I'm using this command in the command line

```
cd ~/COMP167/NZSWebsite && git commit -a -m "Adding file.html"
```

then

```
git push
```

Previously, when I added new files to the COMP167 folder they would be included in the commit. I didn't need to add them manually to the "tracked" files.

Now, instead of being asked to enter my username and password (token) I'm getting the message...

```
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
    file.html

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Does someone know why the behaviour of the commit is working differently now? And how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does someone know why the behaviour of the commit is working differently now

It isn't behaving differently now, no matter what you may think. And this has nothing to do with GitHub, two factor authentication, or the effect of gamma rays on man-in-the-moon marigolds. `git commit -a` doesn't cause new (untracked) files to become tracked. It's right there in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

> ```
> -a
> --all
> ```
>
> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but *new files you have not told Git about are not affected*.

(My italics.)

Comment: Your extra flavour text is unhelpful. People on this forum have varying degrees of experience and training in software, I don't have much, which is why I'm asking rather than answering questions.

Can you please answer the question which is - why is the exact same code doing something different now than it did a month ago. Before it was uploading all new files in the COMP167 folder, but is no longer doing so.

Comment: Well, I was entering the code via a macro, so I'm not sure how I could possibly be typing anything differently since I didn't change the macro. But thanks, I guess, for the "git add ." tip, perhaps that is the answer I've been looking for.

Comment: You are right. I did just have to add "git add ." and it worked. So this solved the problem, it even works for removing files too. So, thanks. If you wanted to include this in your answer, I would accept it as the solution.